# Powershell replace text with Bold in Word

Tags: powershell

I have a script that generates a word document, including adding tables of data and replacing tags with data.

The steps of the report generation are as follows

1. Find and replace tags with data values - Works fine
2. Add tables with data, included in some of this data is a ##value## which I used to do a find and make Bold.

The section of the report generation code is as per below. Everything works as expected, except for changing the key text to Bold. What I dont quite understand is if I run it manually in bits of code, so run the open the document first, and then run the snipped of code that changes to bold it works. But if I run all the code together i.e. run all the replaces, create the tables it doesn't work.

```
Function ReplaceTag($Document, $FindText, $ReplaceWithText)
{
$FindReplace=$Document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find
$matchCase = $false;
$matchWholeWord = $true;
$matchWildCards = $false;
$matchSoundsLike = $false;
$matchAllWordForms = $false;
$forward = $true;
$format = $false;
$matchKashida = $false;
$matchDiacritics = $false;
$matchAlefHamza = $false;
$matchControl = $false;
$read_only = $false;
$visible = $true;
$replace = 2;
$wrap = 1;

$FindReplace.Execute($findText, $matchCase, $matchWholeWord, $matchWildCards, $matchSoundsLike, $matchAllWordForms, $forward, $wrap, $format, $replaceWithText, $replace, $matchKashida ,$matchDiacritics, $matchAlefHamza, $matchControl) | Out-Null
}



$TemplateFile = "..Invetigations_Update_Template1.docx"
$FinalFile = "..Invetigations_Update_Final.docx"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $false
#$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($TemplateFile)
$WordObject = $Word.Selection

ReplaceTag –Document $Doc -FindText '<TotalInvestigatedCases>' -replacewithtext $TotalInvestigatedCases
ReplaceTag –Document $Doc -FindText '<TotalCompletedCases>' -replacewithtext $TotalCompletedCases
ReplaceTag –Document $Doc -FindText '<TotalActiveCases>' -replacewithtext $TotalActiveCases
ReplaceTag –Document $Doc -FindText '<TotalCases>' -replacewithtext $TotalCases


$searchText=$replaceText= 'Investigation Areas To be Explored:'
$wdReplaceAll  = 2
$word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = $true
$word.Selection.Find.Execute($searchText, $false, $true, $false, $false, $false, $true, $false, $true, $replaceText, $wdReplaceAll)


SaveAsWordDoc –document $Doc –Filename $FinalFile
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Your `$Total*` variabes are all undefined and what is function `ReplaceTag` ?

Comment: Hi Theo,

The $total variables are all defined elsewhere and to make it easier to read I've excluded those. Ultimately they do work and replace the variables

The function itself I've added to the original post

thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling `$word.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()` and `$word.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()` methods beforehand?  Not sure if that helps, but most MS documentation shows it.

Comment: Hi, I've tried adding both lines and I get the same result    

`$word.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting()
$word.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting()
$searchText=$replaceText= 'Investigation Areas To be Explored'
$wdReplaceAll  = 2
$word.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = 1
$word.Selection.Find.Execute($searchText, $false, $true, $false, $false, $false, $true, $false, $true, $replaceText, $wdReplaceAll)`

Comment: For what it's worth, in my script I found I couldn't easily pass the word objects into a function. Instead I had to declare global vars e.g. `$global:wordobj = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application` and then inside the function you can define an object based on the global e.g. `$activetable = $global:wordobj.ActiveDocument.Tables[$global:ActiveHeaderNum]`

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the comment. This section of code do to the find and replace in bold, I've left outside of a function and it still comes back with false, as in nothing to change. What I've noticed is if I save the document, add a section of code at the end that re-opens, the find and replace in bold works